# Combining geometric distribution with binomial

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $N \sim \operatorname{Geo}(p)$, so $\mathbb{P}(N=k)=(1-p)^k p$, $k=0,1,2,\dots$, and $N_R | N \sim \operatorname{Bin}(\alpha,N)$.

I am trying to find a distribution of $N_R$, it is fairly easy to write down $$\mathbb{P}(N_R=k)=\sum_{n=k}^\infty \binom{n}{k} \alpha^k(1-\alpha)^{n-k}(1-p)^n p,$$ but I do not see an easy way of evaluating it.

Another approach is to look at the probability generating functions, to deduce that
$$G_{N_R}(z)=G_N(\alpha z+1-\alpha)=\frac{p}{1-(1-p)(\alpha z+1-\alpha)},$$
and I can't recognise this as a PGF of anything familiar.

Is the distribution of $N_R$ well-known distribution (or a mixture of two well-known distributions), but I just don't see it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: There exists $q$ depending on $p$ and $\alpha$ such that $G_{N_R}(z)=\dfrac{q}{1-(1-q)z}$, hence $N_R$ is geometric with parameter $q$.

Comment: Is there a way to see that such q exists straight away?

Comment: Yes, the pgf is a rational function with constant numerator and linear denominator, like that of the geometric rv. This, along with pgf(1) = 1 fixes all the coefficients uniquely.

Comment: Of course, Maclaurin expansion will make it a geometric RV!

Answer (score 0):

The generating function explanation by Did is good.  Here is an alternate, more "combinatorial" explanation.

We can think of $N$ as resulting from the following process.  We have an infinite sequence of the letters A and B.  Each letter is independent and takes value A with probability $p$ and B with probability $1-p$.  Then $N$ is the position of the first A (with 0 being the first position).  Equivalently it is the number of B's before the first A.

A similar process describes $N_R$ except now each letter in the sequence is distributed as follows:

- A with probability $p$
- B with probability $\alpha(1-p)$
- C with probability $(1-\alpha)(1-p)$

Now $N_R$ is the number of B's before the first A.  The C's are just ignored.

Since we ignore the C's we can proceed by conditioning on the location of all the C's.  Regardless of their locations, the remaining locations contain a string of A's and B's, each independently equal to A with probability $\frac{p}{p + \alpha(1-p)}$.  This shows that $N_R$ is a geometric distribution with parameter $\frac{p}{p + \alpha(1-p)}$.

This has application to physics.  The number of photons in the Maxwell–Boltzmann distribution is given by a geometric distribution.  If the light passes through a medium that absorbs each photon with probability $1-\alpha$ then this argument shows that we are left with a different Maxwell–Boltzmann distribution, meaning that the state is still thermal but at a different temperature.